# I'm having trouble with falling objects with constant mass flow rate

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

So it follows that F=d(mv)/dt and so F = m dv/dt + v dm/dt

It is given that there is some sand flowing with constant massflow rate M dropped from a height h and we are to find the force exerted on the surface it falls. This means that the velocity can be found using conservation of energy where mgh=1/2mv^2 so sqrt(2gh) = v

What I'm having trouble understanding why dv/dt in this system should be zero. I thought that dv/dt => a and so the acceleration should be g? However when I was taught this topic the professors said dv/dt should be zero but I don't understand why this is.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The velocity does change in time, but when solving the problem this way you don't need to think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your equation for conservation of energy, $v=\sqrt{2gh}$ is the final velocity with which the sand hits the ground. The sand is falling from a constant height so final velocity $v$ does not change : neither $h$ nor $g$ is changing. Of course the velocity of the sand increases from the point of release, but this variable velocity is not the final velocity $v=\sqrt{2hg}$ which you have calculated from the conservation of energy.